# Is there a way to include holiday calendar into Quantity system?

Tags: units

Suppose I have a long list of business hours but in different denominations for postings like as follows. If I just use the vanilla `UnitConvert` it just does a blanket convert without taking into account holidays in the country or weekends.

```
UnitConvert[#,("Hours")/("Years")]&/@{Quantity[9.,("Hours")/("Day")],Quantity[38.,("Hours")/("Weeks")],Quantity[160.,("Hours")/("Months")],Quantity[2040.,("Hours")/("Years")],...}
```

- for day to year, it just uses 1 year has 365 days
- for week to year, it just uses 1 year has 365/7 weeks
- for months to year, it just uses 1 year has 12 months
- for year to year, it just uses 1 year has 1 year

But, I would like to convert the unit to working hours per annum or some common denomination taking into account which days are holidays or weekends since they are business hours not just vanilla hours.

Does Mathematica have a dated localized business unit for `"Hours"` (like `DatedAndLocalized["BusinessHours",DateObject[{2020},"Year","Gregorian"],Entity["City",{"Toronto","Ontario","Canada"}]]` which would take into account the number of business days in the specified year in specific location rather than do vanilla transformation?

Comment: Have you looked at [DayRange](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DayRange.html)?

Comment: I second `DayRange` with "BusinessDay" and `HolidayCalendar` option specified (a country will work, not sure about provinces) - but it needs to be anchored in a calendar, so one needs the starting moment/day. From there one can extract number of working days and convert them to hours by multiplication by most likely 8.